# React/redux : this.props returns undefined value + array

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-props

I am using React/redux to build my app.

Here is my data (json)

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "category 1",
      "slug": "category-1"
      "content": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "title 1 "
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "title 2 "
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

what I want to do :

1. select a category
2. display the content of the category selected

my store is like that :

```
categoryItems: [], // list of categories
categorySelected: []
```

data is saved correctly on my state when I select a category

on Category component I implement the function selectCategory which calls the action SELECT_CATEGORY and dispatch data to reducer. so far so good!

```
getCategoryList() {
   return this.props.categories.map((category) => {
     return (<li key={category.id}> 
            <Link to={`/category/${category.slug}`} onClick={() =>this.props.selectCategory(category.slug)} >{category.name} </Link>)});}
```

and on CategoryDetail, when I console.log(this.props.categorySelected.name) I got:

```
undefined
name
```

here is the problem because I can not read this.props.categorySelected.name
How to fix this and read proprely this props?

Comment: Are u sure that only `{category.name}` is undefined ? could you try to validate the others properties of that object to see what print ?

Comment: All propreties of that object are undefined. Example : if I console log category.id, the it shows undefined and id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the complete object to your `selectCategory()` function.

Like this:

```
getCategoryList() {
   return this.props.categories.map((category) => {
     return (<li key={category.id}> 
            <Link to={`/category/${category.slug}`} onClick={() =>this.props.selectCategory(category)} >{category.name} </Link>)});
}
```